# How to recover from deleting menubar?

Tags: application-development, python, quickly

I am working with Ubuntu Quickly, and I ran the `quickly design` command, then deleted the menubar.  But when I run, i get this error:

```
AttributeError: UiFactory instance has no attribute 'helpMenu'
```

I tried commenting out sections, but a simple search of the source code doesn't show helpMenu.

And google search for "Quickly" gives you a LOT of false positives ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from the modified base Window class that quickly has in _lib/Window.py:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/testapp", line 33, in <module>
    testapp.main()
  File "/home/ian/pythontesting/testapp/testapp/__init__.py", line 33, in main
    window = TestappWindow.TestappWindow()
  File "/home/ian/pythontesting/testapp/testapp_lib/Window.py", line 35, in __new__
    new_object.finish_initializing(builder)
  File "/home/ian/pythontesting/testapp/testapp/TestappWindow.py", line 24, in finish_initializing
    super(TestappWindow, self).finish_initializing(builder)
  File "/home/ian/pythontesting/testapp/testapp_lib/Window.py", line 61, in finish_initializing
    LaunchpadIntegration.add_items(self.ui.helpMenu, 1, True, True)
AttributeError: UiFactory instance has no attribute 'helpMenu'
```

The builder no longer has a menu.  It's in a try/except block so should fail nicely but doesn't because it won't handle attribute errors. Modify the Window.py file so that line 63 reads:

```
except (ImportError, AttributeError):
```

Now it should work and does for me. I submitted a bug report to launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/quickly/+bug/1051686